# ASP.NET Core on Windows 10: Cannot find System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml 4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I have a .NET Core MVC Application, with the following `project.json` dependencies and tools:

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
"System.Runtime.Serialization.Json" : "4.0.0",
"System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml" : "4.0.0",
"SpinWorks.JobManager.SpecificModels": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "target": "project"
  }
 },

"tools": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
 },
```

Notice that I added the following on purpose:

```
"System.Runtime.Serialization.Json" : "4.0.0",
"System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml" : "4.0.0",
```

This is the error I get during runtime:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
  An unhandled exception has occurred: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Have you ran a `dotnet restore`?

Comment: @DavidG, just a second fast you were. :D

Comment: Yes I restored already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change versions as below. It should work.

```
 "System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml": "4.1.1",
```

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you explained why this solves the problem